# Putting Select Statement on Hibernate Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have been reading for a while regarding Hibernate but I can't seem to understand one concept regarding `Transaction`.

On some sites that I have visit, `Select` statements are in transaction mode like this.

```
public List<Book> readAll() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
            .getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Book> booksList = session.createQuery("from Book").list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return booksList;
}
```

While on some site, it does not advocate the use of transaction on `Select` statements:

```
public List<Book> readAll() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
            .getCurrentSession();
    List<Book> booksList = session.createQuery("from Book").list();
    return booksList;
}
```

I am thinking which one should I follow. Are transactions needed on `Select` Statements or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the use case.

In a typical CRUD style web application a common entity configuration is to use versioning and optimistic locking. [(hibernate annotation docs)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity-version)  If the application is using optimistic locking, dirty reads are probably not that important, and there is no need to put the select in a transaction.

When dirty reads are not acceptable, then a transaction for the select is appropriate.  Most of the time, with that kind of scenario, the select will be done in conjunction with some data modification that requires full consistency for a point in time.

Answer (score 3):

`session.getTransaction().commit()` is used to persist your changes to database, use it if you changed in database like insert or update

Comment: please use real language, u is not appropriate

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd And who are you to decide which language is appropriate?! To me it seems that telling people how to speak is both unconstructive and rude - that kind of behaviour I truly consider inappropriate

Comment: @mojojojo I am not the one to decide, the decision has been made by the site owners. [English is the official language](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/), and leet speak is not acceptable English.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd There's not a word about using reductions in that document. So this leaves us with you using ridiculous excuses to go offtopic and start preaching people

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall, hibernate requires a transaction for everything. Try running it without a transaction and see if it fails.

I've been using it with spring and JPA lately, and if I forget to open a transaction (by an annotation), a read-only transaction is started. But that may be spring specific.

Answer (score 1):

You have the choice to use the transaction here as either way you can get the same result.

Unless you are going to make some changes to the data, you do not need a transaction. some would like to havea transaction always when they interact with DB, but thats just a convention. In which case you can use a readonly transaction using `session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.NEVER);`

Also you are better off using

> ***session.createCriteria(Book.class).list();***
>
> As any refactoring would change the query automatically.